# Garage door not operating correctly

Tags: garage

My garage door opener is a Linear. It opens fine with either the hard wired button or remote. It will not close at all with remote. It will not close with the hard wired button unless you hold your finger on the down button until all the way down. If you only click the down button it starts down and immediately goes back up like something is in the line of sight of the safety switches.

The tow lights on the safety beam sensors are both green all the time. No red and nothing else lights up. I've checked all wiring, pulled the hard wired button apart and cleaned it. Tried to align the safety sensors and nothing will fix the problem.

Is it likely that my safety switches have gone bad? the door is only 6 years old and does not get used every day.

Comment: Unhook the opener.  Does the garage door open freely by hand?

Answer (score 1):

If I've found the right documentation for your opener, it says the lights should be red for a good beam.  You should also get a set of flashes that indicate the fault after you press the button.  Three flashes are for a sensor fault.

https://www.linearproaccess.com/wp-content/uploads/LDO_user.pdf

Follow the troubleshooting steps in the doc to see if they help.

Comment: Side note: having a green LED be "bad" and a red LED be "good" is about as confusing as it could be...

Comment: Those direction are great. The contractor that installed the door and opener left me nothing. I doubled checked wiring and lenses. I can not find a short in any wiring. I do get 3 light flashes when trying to close. So all indications are the sensors out of alignment or just plain shot I suppose. They both have power as both have only a green light on at all times. Nothing I've tried gets one red of of either one. I am not sure which is the sender & which is receiver. One has a large clear round lens while the other has a small bulb about the same size as the red/green lights on the sensors.

Comment: It may help to disconnect the sensors and connect them to the opener with a set of short wires on the top of a step ladder.  This way you can rule out the wiring and the sensors will be very close to each other.

Comment: Good idea I'll try that soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when the safety sensors "detect" that something is in the way. The sensors are mis-aligned, improperly powered, or just broken: it's hard to tell without more information.

Comment: There is nothing in the way and I have tried to realign them a couple of times. None of the lights on the sensors change. Both only ever display a small green light.

Comment: Do the lights stay green when the beam is blocked?

Comment: Always green no mater what at both sensors.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the emmiter is usually the failure point you may be able to test the receiver with a strong flashlight , they are sometimes infrared but a strong light may cause it to toggle then you know it's the emitter that is bad.

Comment: Which sensor is the "emitter"?

Comment: Usually emitters have 2 wires the receiver has 3 the emitter most likely is the one that has the bulb if you can see it they are usually LED's in the non visible spectrum.